# HttpClient https request fails using hostname, but works using IP address

Tags: c#, https, dotnet-httpclient

I am new to web stuff in general. Not sure what the issue is here.

I have a machine with IIS running a ASP NET Core REST API on https.
I can confirm the GET is working via Google Chrome on my machine by doing either

- https://test-machine/api/Example (works)
- https://10.0.0.21/api/Example (invalid certificate, N.B. ***this is as expected*** as the certificate is for "test-machine")

I confirmed the POST action is working using Postman (again ignoring invalid certificate). 
Everything is fine till I try and write a client application.

#### I have the following code.

```
var ip = Dns.GetHostAddresses("test-machine");
// ip contains the correct IP 

using (var hc = new HttpClient())
{
    hc.GetAsync(@"https://test-machine/api/Example").Wait();
}
```

This code fails. I get an System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred.' with 4 exceptions stacked up on top of one another.

1. HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
2. WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
3. IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
4. SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

#### If I change the code to use the IP instead:

```
using (var hc = new HttpClient())
{
    hc.GetAsync(@"https://10.0.0.21/api/Example").Wait();
}
```

Then the request works **as expected** I.e. as with Chrome, I get a certificate problem:

> AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

What am I doing wrong? The Dns is clearly able to get the correct IP, I've seen it in the `IPAddress[]` returned by `GetHostAddresses`. Why is the HttpClient not resolving the IP - or is it resolving the IP with another problem?

I have tried

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

and

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

but this makes no difference. Using the

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback
```

Also doesn't work as it never reaches the point of calling the callback. It's failing before then.

I suspect the problem is that as I am not familiar with any of this stuff I have missed something important somewhere.

I should note also - this is a .net 4.5.2 Console app. I tried moving to 4.6.1 and this still fails.

Comment: Does the url load in Internet Explorer 11?

Comment: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` Your cert supports TLS1.2?

Comment: Honestly, my suggestion in these cases is to get the cert working.

Comment: Unrelated: [You're using HttpClient wrong](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) and [Using HttpClient As It Was Intended (Because You’re Not)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1194406/Using-HttpClient-as-it-was-intended-because-you-re)

Comment: @Fildor I am aware of that - it's only an example :)

Comment: @mjwills Doesn't load in IE11 - I get `Cannot securely connect to this page - This might be because the site uses outdated or unsafe TLS security settings. If this keeps happening, try contacting the website’s owner.`

Comment: Also - Doesn't matter if I use `SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`or skip the whole thing

Comment: Finally - the certificate seems to work in chrome. (Padlock with `Certificate Valid` text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking completely in the wrong place. The problem lay in the IIS setup.

The site binding was for some reason explicitly set to 10.0.0.21:433. Switching this to "All Unassigned" - seems to have made this work.

I am probably out of my depth, and could be wrong, but I suspect the reason for this is that according to Wireshark, the response to the MDNS request to find the hostname IP, was returning the **ipv6** address of the server machine, which of course isn't 10.0.0.21. Again, I could be wrong.

The reason I am so unsure is that chrome seems to have ploughed right through and found the correct thing when I put in https://test-machine/api/Example and I cannot explain why.